# Content of SessionStorage in Chrome is not displayed anymore

Tags: google-chrome, session, local-storage, google-chrome-devtools

Since yesterday I have following problem: The variables in session storage are not visible anymore in chrome/devtools under session storage. In the console, I can call the variables, so they're here, but not visible.

So far the only way I could solve this problem is by changing my chrome profile to "gast". Then I can see the variable back. But I don't know which settings should I do to make it work under my regular profile.

Anyone a clue?

Comment: There's no such setting in devtools, so the problem is either in Chrome (e.g. you've disabled cookies on this site) or in your code.

Comment: Can't be in my code, bec my work mates have the same code and no problem. And as i said, when changing the chrome profile it works. So the problem is definitely somewhere in Chrome

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and I just solved and it was very simple.

1 - Open devTools and go to Settings

2 - In Preferences roll to the bottom of the page and select the "Restore defaults and reload" option.

Answer (score 2):

I'm seeing the same thing, the localStorage preview sometimes gets stuck and is not updating. Reload or reset of preferences is not helping.
Reported it here: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1414104

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue.

My teammates could see data in the application tab, but I could not.

What solved the problem was running:

chrome://restart

in the address bar.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by removing the previous session key and storing it again.

`sessionStorage.removeItem("key");`

`sessionStorage.setItem("key", "value");`